# Iterating by reference on a C++ vector with foreach

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, reference, stl

Does it make any sense to do something like:

```
void my_fun(std::vector<int>& n)
    {
        for (int& i : n) 
            {
                do something(i);
            }
    }
```

compared to a normal foreach loop without the reference? Would the value be passed by copy otherwise?

Comment: Yes, if you do not use a reference you get a copy.

Comment: if possible it should be `for (const int& i : n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does what you think it does assuming that the signature of `do_something` is `void do_something(int& i)`.

If you don't put the ampersand in the range-based for-loop you'll get a copy.